# Monochrome ISA graphics adapter with the smallest footprint

Tags: isa, mda

I am designing an x86 retro computer, and I can't find a suitable 8-bit ISA graphics adapter for it. I don't need much in terms of graphics: mostly I need a text mode in black and white, some kind of graphic mode or shades of gray would be nice, but not a requirement. My design is small, so I would like a solution that would fit the small form factor of my build.

I have considered the following chips:

- SiS   86C22
- Tamarack  TD3088A
- Tamarack  TD3088A2
- Tamarack  TD3088A3
- Tamarack  TD3088A5
- Tamarack  RY-3301
- Winbond   W86855AF
- NEC   μPD65042GD
- Acer  M3127

Most of them only require some passives, a 16 MHz crystal, two DRAM chips, and some supporting TTL logic. Character ROM is optional, and they all have LPT that I am not going to use.

The absolute winner in the smallest footprint is TD3088A3/TD3088A5, however I can't find this chip for sale anywhere except for on ISA graphic cards in working condition, which I do not want to destroy.

The chip that I actually could find listed for sale from multiple (equally shady) sources is  W86855AF. However, there's absolutely no documentation on it. It seems that there are a lot of MDA/Hercules compatible ISA cards using a QFP100 chip with very similar layout. So maybe there's documentation available for at least one of them?

What should be the best approach in finding suitable parts for such system?

Comment: When you say "ISA", I think "strict IBM PC compatible". But when you start talking "shades of gray", I think "CGA in monochrome mode" because MDA didn't do graphics and Hercules just did a straight bitmap of the MDA screen with no shades/colors (just on/off for each pixel). So clarify this a bit: Are you trying to make an x86 computer with an arbitrary low-end graphics card? Or are you trying to make an IBM PC compatible with MDA/Hercules compatibility? Or an IBM PC compatible with CGA with a monochrome monitor? Or something else? If anything other than strict PC clone, what resolution?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: Monochrome text mode, whether on Hercules or the MDA, had two intensity levels apart from black.  I don't think the original Hercules card offered intensity control, but I think some of its successors did.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there doesn't appear to be any input the community can give. The choice seems to be between documented yet unavailable and undocumented yet available: not a useful choice